# jboss 7.1 xalan issue?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, xalan

I am attempting to create an Apache Jena based application on JBoss7.

Apache Jena uses Xalan 2.11.0
JBoss 7 ships with 2.7.1

When I attempt to call the application I get an exception, the root of which is:

org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: Schema factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl does not extend from SchemaDVFactory

I suspect this is because of the difference in version.  I read through the Module documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction) and attempted to change ot Xalan 2.11.0, but no luck: Jboss just froze on startup.  Has anybody done this successfully or, alternatively, does anyone know how to override the Xalan for a deployment?

Thx

Comment: What Xalan 2.11.0 there is no such thing see project web site: http://xalan.apache.org/ Do you maybe think of xerces?

Answer (score 7):

JBoss 7 or JBoss EAP 6 ships with its own xalan version, that you can find among its modules,
in jboss eap 6.1:

`<JBoss Home>/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/xalan/main`

if you want to use your own first you have to exclude jboss xalan with the below jboss deployment descriptor in `/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` for war and `/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` for ear:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>            
        <exclusions>            
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
            <module name="org.apache.xerces" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I excluded also Xerces, because usually they are bundled toghether.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the CBU (Carbon Based Unit)  I was playing with xalan when I should have been playing with xerces.  It is xerces 2.11 (DOH)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to maybe deploy your application with `/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and explicitly exclude JBoss-provided libraries that you want to override, and then just package them yourself in the application, e.g. `/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.11.0.jar`

Here's an example of jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.xalan" />
            <module name="SOME.OTHER.MODULE.YOU.DONT.WANT.JBOSS.TO.PROVIDE" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I have not tested this, though. Try it if it works and report. We'll try another approach if that doesn't work.