# Getting DVFactoryException when instantiating a new EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly, xerces

I'm developing a Java web application for Wildfly 9.

I wrote this persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="Win-Data-PU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <property name = "hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.klopotek.core.connection.MyHibernateConnectionProvider" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:comp/persistence/Api" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="Dynamic-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.klopotek.win.core.connection.DynamicConnectionProvider" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

As you can see I defined a new Hibernate Connection Provider for both the Persistence Units.

Now I'm trying to instantiate a new EntityManagerFactory for the second PU:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Dynamic-PU");
```

But I get this exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to locate persistence units
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:69)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at com.my.ExportService.exportDbDirect(ExportService.java:107)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at com.klopotek.core.auth.filter.KasPrincipalFilter.doFilter(KasPrincipalFilter.java:54)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.UndertowAuthenticatedActionsHandler.handleRequest(UndertowAuthenticatedActionsHandler.java:66)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.undertow.ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(ServletPreAuthActionsHandler.java:69)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.DVFactoryException: Schema factory class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.xs.SchemaDVFactoryImpl does not extend from SchemaDVFactory.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:75)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.SchemaDVFactory.getInstance(SchemaDVFactory.java:57)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.reset(XMLSchemaLoader.java:1027)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:559)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:538)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:255)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:638)
    at __redirected.__SchemaFactory.newSchema(__SchemaFactory.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.resolveLocalSchema(PersistenceXmlParser.java:435)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.v21Schema(PersistenceXmlParser.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.validate(PersistenceXmlParser.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.loadUrl(PersistenceXmlParser.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.parsePersistenceXml(PersistenceXmlParser.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.doResolve(PersistenceXmlParser.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser.locatePersistenceUnits(PersistenceXmlParser.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:97)
    ... 67 more
```

It seems that in the inner process of EMF creation Java finds that [this](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/impl/dv/xs/SchemaDVFactoryImpl.html) class doen't extend [this](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/impl/dv/SchemaDVFactory.html)

If you see in the declaration, however, SchemaDVFactoryImpl implements SchemaDVFactory.

EDIT: 
I'm using

- Java JDK 1.8.0_77 but the same problem arises with Java JDK 1.8.0_66
- WildFly Full 9.0.2.Final
- Hibernate 4.3.10.Final

What do you think is happening in you opinion?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207490/jboss-7-1-xalan-issue

Comment: So you think it's a matter of buggy version of Xerces and/or Xalan on the Wildfly 9.0.2 server?

Comment: i think you have a duplicate version in your deployment

Comment: @FedericoSierra: this is the answer. Is you write the answer to the question I will accept yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss/Wildfly include its own **Xerces/Xalan** version, then you must exclude from your deployment or exclude Wildfly modules with the [jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Class+Loading+in+WildFly).